# MYSQL Natural Language Search, can it be used to search against a table?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to use MQSQL's MATCH() function against a table?

Basically, I have two columns in two separate tables that I'd like to search on. I want to search for matches for every row in Column 1 for potential matches in Column 2.

Everything I've read so far has MATCH using a static search term. I would assume the only way would be to write a script to iterate through every result no?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL [MATCH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) does this exactly. Check the documentation, there are also examples.